# Checking if a string is a binary notation of a number

Tags: python, python-requests

[image]

There is a program in which I have to catch an error using «raise».A string arrives(self.source) and you need to check if this string is not a binary notation for a number, then we call raise. The problem is that if you do it through (int(self.source, 2) is False:), then int(self.sorce, 2) give a  ValueError. How can this be checked briefly?
Self.source my be = „0bhdhdudjrh” or
“Ob00001fud” or “djxuxhdhh” and in that case should call raise

Comment: Please post code, not a picture of code...

Comment: Always share the entire error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could catch the `ValueError` and raise your own error:

```py
try:
    int(self.source, 2)
except ValueError:
    raise MoveError
```

Comment: Yes, I understand, but to do in “if” use «try», doesn’t quite suit me and for program. Thx.

Comment: It is about how to write down this condition (check) in the framework of this “if”

Answer (score 0):

Nest the `if` statement inside a `try`/`except`.

```
try:    
    if self.source not in Elements.components and int(self.source, 2) >= len(Elements.stack) or self.target not in Element.components and int(self.target, 2) >= len(Elements.stack):
        raise MoveError
except ValueError:
    raise MoveError
```